# How to use Vertica's COPY LOCAL as an sql statement from MATLAB on Windows

Tags: sql, matlab, bulkinsert, vertica

I'm trying to insert around 80 million records created using MATLAB into Vertica Database table. I wanted to know if we can call `COPY LOCAL` statement in MATLAB as a regular sql statement using `exec(conn, sql)`. For test purpose, I tried with a dat file having around 4 million records as following:

```
sqlstmnt = 'COPY schema.table_name (FK_CUSTOMER_ID,FK_RUN_START_DATE_ID,FK_RUN_END_DATE_ID,FK_TRAVEL_ID,FK_ORIGIN_ID,FK_DEST_ID,FK_SEGMENT_ID,SEGMENT_PERCENTAGE,LAST_UPDATED) FROM LOCAL ''/my/file/full/path/test1.dat''';

results = exec(conn,sqlstmnt);
```

But it gave an error in `results.Message` like:

> [Vertica]JDBC A ResultSet was expected but not generated from query "COPY schema.table_name(FK_CUSTOMER_ID,FK_RUN_START_DATE_ID,FK_RUN_END_DATE_ID,FK_TRAVEL_ID,FK_ORIGIN_ID,FK_DEST_ID,FK_SEGMENT_ID,SEGMENT_PERCENTAGE,LAST_UPDATED) FROM LOCAL '/my/file/full/path/test1.dat'". Query not executed.

I have the data in the '.dat' file in the order in which the columns are mentioned in `COPY LOCAL`.

I could not find any helpful resource explaining this error.

I have this test1.dat file which I'm able to insert using COPY from vsql but since I run my codes in MATLAB with many iterations,each iteration producing about a million records, I would want to insert them during each iteration. Any help will be really great.

Answer (score 0):

COPY command return ResultSet  that includes the amount of loaded data , i see two main options

1) results =exec(conn,sqlstmnt);

2)results = runsqlscript(conn,'nameOfSQLScriptthatIncludeTheCopyCommand.sql')

I hope you will find it useful

Thanks

Comment: Oh Sorry,I mentioned it as an error explicitly. That error is actually given in the Message part of the cursor 'results' even if I run it as                                         results =exec(conn,sqlstmnt);

Comment: Do you try the secound option ?

Comment: Second option also I tried just now but I got the same error. I tried the same statement in vsql with the file on server,it says "no COPY in progress ". Am I missing anything in the syntax here?

Comment: Please share your target table structure and some sample data from the CSV

Comment: Have shared my files here https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/wiCoZ8iXLROluEoMM1cknA

Answer (score 0):

I just finish  reviewing  you’re your input sample data  .
       i see major problem   with the  mapping of the input  csv to the target table  .

```
Main issues are :
  1)     Lines  are  broken  into 2 lines ( you should prefer having one  sample per line and avoid brock it into 2 lines )
      Eg :  "1,20150101,0,2,2573,2714,1,8.147237e-01
            50,48,49,54,45,48,51,-28 12:11:46"

  2) when you define data types on vertica table ,eg: timestamp the data on the csv must reflect to it ( what you have is "-28 12:11:46" , this will not work )   


    After you fix all this issues ,  make sure you test it  using vsql , then go and try it with matlab 

    I hope you will find it useful.
```

Comment: Actually every alternate lines got added when I saved into '.dat' file from MATLAB. its not actually there in the variable. Still, I will try saving the data in '.csv' file and try again. Because I remember last time I tried on vsql was similar data in a dat file.

Comment: Yes , Bottom line , you need to fix your dat file

Comment: Yup, there was a mistake while writing the dat file. I had missed a column in         fprintf(fid,'%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%s\n',temp_data{row,:});   I have shared the correct data here   https://www.sendspace.com/file/v3s36d          I tried after the correction but still the same issue. Could this be because I'm trying this from Windows(my laptop) to server on linux?

Comment: Glad to hear ! ,please make sure you tag it as a  solution

Comment: Your data include 9 columns ,your target table is 17 columns , make sure you have full map

Comment: That is the reason I'm specifying the column names in the COPY statement. So ideally only those column data should be inserted, right?

Comment: I finally got the mistake. I was not specifying `DELIMITER ','`   So the statement I ran was  `sqlstmnt = 'COPY schema.table_name   (FK_CUSTOMER_ID, FK_RUN_START_DATE_ID,  FK_RUN_END_DATE_I  D, FK_TRAVEL_ID, FK_ORIGIN_ID, FK_DEST_ID, FK_SEGMENT_ID, SEGMENT_PERCENTAGE, LAST_UPDATED) FROM LOCAL '/my/file/full/path/test1.dat' DELIMITER ',' ; `

Comment: Yep , glade to her ,anyway it was both you dat file the missing delimiter part

Comment: I'm sorry again. It is working on vsql but not in MATLAB. :-(

Comment: Yes, I actually tried on vsql after correcting the delimiter and it worked.Then I tried it back on MATLAB and got the same old error.

Comment: Make sure yor code generate the rigth copy and dat fie (same you used for the vsql)

Comment: Yes I checked the code in MATLAB and the path as well. I also tried the same query from DBVisualizer with the same path to the dat file as I gave in MATLAB and from DBVisualizer also the data was inserted into the table in 2.8 seconds. But not happening from MATLAB.    Is it like COPY will work only inside Vertica environment or something?

Comment: Try to use fastinsert method insted of the copy method

Comment: I have tried fastinsert, datainsert, insert but they are all way slower than COPY, that's why I'm totally behind COPY.

Comment: It will intersted to see your dc verica error file (its under the catalog folder search for *error* file),plase share it

Comment: More on that ,as matlab has internal jvm included i advice to use the native java api's to do what you look for (i can send an example if needed) ,this will do what you need for sure

Comment: Example for jdbc embeded ( you should change the driver and the api to do what you need).   
javaclasspath('sqljdbc4.jar'); %# load driver and create connection driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver; conn = driver.connect('jdbc:sqlserver://<HOST>:<PORT>;databaseName=<DB>'); %# query database q = conn.prepareStatement('select * from <TABLE>'); rs = q.executeQuery(); while rs.next() char(rs.getString(0)) end rs.close(); conn.close();

Comment: If I'm not wrong,actually I'm using similar steps to make connection to database. I'm using vertica.jar which is added to javaclasspath and I use the MATLAB function  conn = database('db_name','username','pwd','com.vertica.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:vertica://HOST:PORT/db_name')    And it connects properly to the database. And then I have a string variable  sqlstmnt = 'COPY statement as bfr ';  results = exec(conn,sqlstmnt);    This is the format I'm using.

Comment: Also I could not find any error file under the catalog folder. CopyErrorLogs folder is also empty may be because I did not set LOAD REJECTION or EXCEPTIONS.

Comment: Attach is a reference of how to run copy command from jdbc make sure your code is using the dame apis https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientJDBC/BulkLoadingUsingTheCOPYStatement.htm